# Как упаковать установочный файлы в windows

Tags: windows

Есть например сборка PHP5+MySQL+apache2. Как можно упаковать это всё, т.е. как бы создать установочный файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте через 7ZIP SFX

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос не до конца понятен. Если у вас есть готовая установка - образ диска, то нужно работать с дисковыми утилитами вроде Norton Ghost. Если речь идет о том, чтобы на чистый Windows устанавливать набор пакетов, то все сведется к написанию скрипта, который будет устанавливать пакеты из набора дистрибутивов (или даже скачивая их с сайта). Этот скрипт можно организовать как обычный cmd-файл или powershell-скрипт. Установочный файл можно сделать на основе самораспаковывающегося архива Zip либо на основе инсталлятора WiX.

Comment: Напрмер у меня на компе установлена сборка PHP5+MySQL+apache2, мне её нужно упаковать и установить на другой комп

Answer (score 1):

[Технология IExpress и мастер IExpress](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc817488.aspx).